# Transitioning from VB6 On Error to .Net Try...Catch

Tags: vb6-migration

Our company has recently transitioned from VB6 to VB.NET. Unfortunately all the error handling remains as `On Error GoTo`. This has not made it easy to track down errors that customers send back to tech support. As of now, the blocks of code that the `On Error` surrounds is entire subroutines, not uncommonly hundreds of lines of code for one sub, and possibly making calls to other routines. My question is how to best go about converting to `Try...Catch` blocks. I assume I can just substitute `On Error GoTo Errorline` for `try` and `Errorline` for `catch`. But this seems like too much for one `try...catch` block to encompass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6's big weakness with error-handling is that the runtime does not provide a way for your code to get at the execution stack (method A called method B called method C, etc.) when an exception occurs; even if your `On Error` block catches the exception, you code doesn't know "where it is".  To get around that deficiency, VB6 programmers have learned to enclose every method, in every module, with a catch-all `On Error` block, sometimes so that their own code can keep track of the execution stack for logging purposes.  There were even third-party tools that could be used to instrument your code with `On Error` blocks, for exactly that purpose (VB/Rig, VB-Failsafe).

.Net's `Exception` object, however, does provide a `.StackTrack` property that represents the execution stack to the point of failure, so it's no longer necessary to use `On Error` blocks in every method, just so you can learn where your code failed, post-mortem.

Here is one simple strategy you can use, as you transition:

First, as you suggested, replace all of your "boilerplate" `On Error Goto Errorline` / `:Errorline` with `Try` / `Catch ex As Exception` blocks.  But, do this only in the "top-level" methods where execution can "begin".  In VB, these are usually all of the Event methods in your forms that directly handle system events (`_Click`, `_MouseDown`, `_Timer`, etc.)

Second, remove all the boilerplate error handling from "lower-level" methods -- methods that are merely called from the "top-level" or other "lower-level" methods.

Now you have provided a "safety net" of `Try/Catch` exception handling that will protect your app from dying from an unhandled exception.  When an exception does occur, even deep in the execution stack, your code will unwind back to the nearest `Catch`, usually one of your UI event-handler methods.  But, you will have the `ex.StackTrack` property that documents the execution up to the failure, module by module, method by method, with the source code line-number at each level.

One exception to the above strategy is when you find an error-handling block that is ***not*** boilerplate -- it was written specifically to handle a certain error(s), and to respond specifically.  Leave this code in place, but again replace the `On Error Goto Errorline` / `:Errorline` with `Try` / `Catch ex As Exception`.

Here's a helpful rule of thumb: In your "top-level" methods, enclose the entire method in a "boilerplate" `Try/Catch`.  In your "lower-level" methods, only write `Try/Catch` blocks around code where you can ***anticipate*** that certain exceptions will occur -- ones that your code wants to specifically respond to.

It's not unreasonable, or "too much", for a Try/Catch block to encompass large chunks of code.  You should always strive to keep your methods as short as possible, but there is no reason to arbitrarily truncate or partition a long method just because it's enclosed by a `Try/Catch`.

Comment: This sounds manageable, still monumental, but manageable. Thanks for the input.